# Position Absolute Not Scrolling Properly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an area that contains all my absolutely positioned items.  It works great until its sibling has an `overflow` attached to it.  In the example below, when you start scrolling, the `child` div scrolls as if it's fixed.  If you comment out the `overflow: auto` in the `#app` CSS, you'll get the desired behavior, but obviously the layout is incorrect.  How can I fix this issue without moving the `absolute` div into the `#app` div?

```css
#app {
  height: 200px;
  /* If I take this off, I get the desired behavior */
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.child {
  top: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="content">
    Content 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="absolute">
  <div class="child">
    Shouldn't be fixed when scrolling
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `absolute` positioning on `.absolute` you'll have to nest that code within `#app` and set it to `position: relative;`. The `absolute` positioning is referring to its nearest positioned ancestor, in this case, the `body` element, hence, why it is staying fixed. So you'll have to set `#app` to `relative` and it should work just fine.

```css
#app {
  height: 200px;
  /* If I take this off, I get the desired behavior */
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.child {
  top: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="content">
    Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="absolute">
    <div class="child">
      Shouldn't be fixed when scrolling
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This should also work for you, see changes I made to HTML and CSS below.

```css
#app {
  height: 200px;
  /* If I take this off, I get the desired behavior */
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.absolute {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.child {
  top: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  color: black;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="content">Content 1
    <div class="absolute">
      <div class="child">
        Shouldn't be fixed when scrolling
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this.  I eventually run into a clipping issue where the absolutely positioned item doesn't show over the content... think of a select dropdown.